# How would I merge these two tables into one table and create a recursive relationship?

Tags: sql, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I am totally confused on how I would merge these two tables and create a recursive relationship. I have attached a picture of the two tables.

[image: the two tables, customer and staff]

Comment: Can you please define the relationship between the Customers and Staff?

Comment: I can't see any kind of recursive information here?